# Split action bar bottom color

Tags: java, android, xml

I have split up the action bar in the manifest file like so:

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

Which works fine, however the menu action buttons (in `res/menu`) on the bottom bar are on a gray background.

I have tried various ways to change this and to get the bottom bar blue. The top action bars are blue as expected, however the bottom is the default gray and I cannot  change it.

The `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <color name="blue">#3D589B</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarbackgroundSplit</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item> <!-- This does the magic! -->
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarbackgroundSplit"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

What is the appropriate style to change the bottom bar with the icons on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some further research (typically after I post the question) the appropriate tag is

```
backgroundSplit
```

I initially used `backgroundStacked`.

So complete section looks like:

```
<style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getActionBar().setSplitBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
```

Try this

Comment: Helpful.  Thanks.